# How can I replace a specific part of a value in a dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to change the value of a dictionary in my program, but nothing seems to work. I also don't get any errors, the value just doesn't change.
I've got this list of Dictionaries:

```
dataDict = [
    {'Time' : 13, 'ID' : 18, 'TeID' : 02, 'LineNum' : 09, 'Sentence' : 'Workload for the week was 100% higher than expected.'}, 
    {'Time' : 03, 'ID' : 36, 'TeID' : 04, 'LineNum' : 11, 'Sentence' : '<FONT size="5"><B>\nHigh Workloads Hit Service Levels</FONT></B> \n<BR><FONT size="4"><FONT style="text-transform: capitalize;">\ncalls and average handle time</FONT> Up So Average Service Level Down To 92.2%.</FONT>'}, 
    {'Time' : 16, 'ID' : 22, 'TeID' : 09, 'LineNum' : 12, 'Sentence' : '<BR><BR>While not the main issue, there was a lot of unscheduled assistance contributing to low service levels.'}
]
```

As you'll be able to see there are 3 `'Sentence'` Keys, 1 for each dictionary in this list. The first `'Sentence' Key contains a string value, but the second key has a line of HTML code which has 2 pieces of text inside it. The third key also has a small amount of HTML code at the beginning of it's text, but it's pretty insignificant.

In the program I've written, the value of each `'Sentence'` key is copied into a dictionary (called `first`), each with a new key: `"stringX"` where 'X' is replaced by whatever number it's assigned when it's put in. The numbers are in ascending order and they're simply just a way to tell the difference between `"string1"` and `"string2"`. Those values are then put through an algorithm I made that strips them of their HTML tags (if they have any) and are then stored in another dictionary (called `htmlNew`) with the same `"stringX"` key system. I should also mention that some values, such as the second 'Sentence' in the original `dataDict` list, have 2 separate bodies of text in their values. This HTML algorithm also separates them, and stores one as `"stringN"` and the other as `"stringN.5"`. This dictionary is then passed through a local AI that rephrases each value from the `htmlNew` dictionary and stores the new output into a dictionary called `response`. Each value is stored as `"responseX"` where X is the same number that the value had in the `htmlNew` dictionary.

This is where I encounter my problem. What I want to do is replace the values of each `'Sentence'` key in the `dataDict` list, but only at specific places as to not remove the original HTML tags. The first one, I figured, shouldn't be a problem since it's just a regular string with no HTML, but even that one isn't being changed. What my plan was, was to use python's `variable.replace(n, x, y)` function, where `n = htmlNew["string1]"` and `x = response["response1"]` (`y` will just be 1).

*/Please note that these `n` and `x` variables don't exist in my code, I just used them for explanation purposes./*

I created a whole loop for the following code but it just changes the `"stringX"` number - this is what I'm doing with each number in said loop:

`dataDict[0]['Sentence'].replace(htmlNew["string1"], response["response1"], 1)`

*/Please note that each number in that line of code (excluding the final '1') changes in the loop I have/*

No error is raised but 'dataDict' remains unchanged. There is also an `if` statement that'll do the same should that current number in the loop also come with a `.5` partner.

I tried `str(dataDict[0]['Sentence'])` before the `.return()' function which did make the function change font in my code editor, so I now believe that that function can only work for strings. I made a copy of the` dataDict` list and I cast the whole list as a string and even that didn't work. Same output though, no change but no error.

Does anyone know how to replace a specific part of a dictionary value with a new value? The HTML in `dataDict` must not change. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be a lot clearer if you simply gave an example of your expected resulting dictionary. Also it is much better to post actual code than try to describe it; ideally in a simplified form which captures your basic problem.

Comment: @user19077881 Thanks for the tips, and I'm sorry if it wasn't very clear. I've had an account with Stack Overflow for over a year just to view questions, but this is the 3rd question I've asked and all 3 were in the space of a week. I'll be sure to apply these pointers in my next question - I'm learning as I go along :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataDict[0]['Sentence'].replace(htmlNew["string1"], response["response1"], 1)` doesn't mutate the dictionary, `str.replace` just returns a new string.

I presume what you need to do is:

```
newstr = dataDict[0]['Sentence'].replace(htmlNew["string1"], response["response1"], 1)
dataDict[0]['Sentence'] = newstr
```